# Transparent Shader using GLSL

Tags: opengl-es, shader, opengl-es-2.0

I'm having a problem with fragment shader as you can see in the image below.

[image]

I don't want to render the parts that are in red in the image
I have to passes which culls clockwise and anticlockwise
and I'm getting the dot product of the normal with the camera position
if its less than 0 I set a transparent fragment
otherwise discard the fargment
here is the shader

```
#version 100

precision mediump float;

varying float  lightDiffuse;

void main()
{
    float light = ( 1.0 - lightDiffuse) * 0.5;
    vec3 lightColor = vec3(0.0,1.0,1.0);
    vec3 diffuseColor = lightColor * light ;

    vec4 c;
    if(lightDiffuse <0.0 )
    {
        // back faces, opaque
        // front faces, very transparent
        c  = vec4(diffuseColor, 0.2);
    }
    else
    {
        discard;
    }

    gl_FragColor = c;
}
```

```
#version 100
#define lowp
#define mediump
#define highp

attribute vec4 vertex;
attribute vec3 normal;

uniform mat4 normalMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelViewProjectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelView;
uniform vec3 camera_world_position;

varying highp float lightDiffuse;

void main()
{      
    gl_Position = modelViewProjectionMatrix * vertex;

    vec3 norm = normal;
    norm *=-1.0;
    lightDiffuse = dot(normalize(vec3(norm.x, norm.y, norm.z)), normalize(camera_world_position));
}
```

here is the material script

```
material 44267_1508405690_0##carpaint
{
    technique
    {
        pass
        {

            cull_hardware anticlockwise
            scene_blend alpha_blend
            vertex_program_ref char_shader2_vs100 
            {
                param_named_auto modelViewProjectionMatrix worldviewproj_matrix
                param_named_auto normalMatrix inverse_transpose_world_matrix
                param_named_auto modelView worldview_matrix
                param_named_auto camera_world_position camera_position

            }
            fragment_program_ref char_shader2_fs100
            {

            }
        }


   pass
        {

            cull_hardware clockwise

            vertex_program_ref char_shader2_vs100 
            {
                param_named_auto modelViewProjectionMatrix worldviewproj_matrix
                param_named_auto normalMatrix inverse_transpose_world_matrix
                param_named_auto modelView worldview_matrix
                param_named_auto camera_world_position camera_position

            }
            fragment_program_ref char_shader2_fs100
            {

            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: So... what's the problem? You say what you're doing, but you're not saying what problem you're having.

Comment: @NicolBolas As in the picture, I see two faces that are overlapping.. I want to discard that effect.. I just want to see what my eyes look not to see the two faces are overlapping as in the image

Comment: The algorithm you describe only works if the normals of the vertices are flat normals. If you have a smooth mesh, then the vertex normals are not necessarily the same as the face normal. Also, you get problems if a vertex is used in more than one face.

Comment: @BDL so what's the solution to this problem ? Thanks for your input

Comment: You can, for example, use a geometry shader and calculate the real face normal. Or, since you are just emulating backface culling, enable real backface culling.

Comment: I can't access geometry shader, I'm using Opengles 2

Comment: @BDL I enable back face culling.. using ogre hardware cull face clockwise and anticlockwise

Comment: If you have backface culling enabled, how can it then be that you have backfacing triangles in your fragment shader?

Comment: I have enabled back face culling and removed the dot product with the normal.. just output a color pixel with alpha value.. but look at this picture.. https://imgur.com/a/IRZoy
it still renders backfaces

Comment: @BDL I have updated the question.. with the two passes code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to cull occluded triangles, allocate a depth buffer and use a depth test, it's what it exists for.

Don't do facing tests in the fragment shader, that's not necessary and horribly expensive, just enable `GL_CULL_FACE` and set the front face correctly. Note that not all models downloaded off the internet get this right, so you might have an input model with broken winding for some triangles.